# Unable to install .net 4.8 runtime or any updates

Tags: .net, updates, dism

Updates always fail on my 2016 server standard vm. When attempting to install .net 4.8 runtime i received the error the component store has been corrupted. I have attempted DISM /ONLINE /CLEANUP-IMAGE /RESTOREHEALTH and received the error The source files could not be found.

I have since tried using other sources including the original iso used to install the os in the virtual DVD drive using DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:D:sourcesinstall.wim:2 /LimitAccess which returned this "The source files could not be found. Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore

ion on specifying a source location, see `http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077`.``"

Also tried using another server in the domain by sharing the windows drive and using this command Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:\SERVER03\Windows /limitaccess and received the same error as previous attempt.

Additionally tried sfc /scannow and received this error "Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some

of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For

example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. Note that logging is currently not

supported in offline servicing scenarios." after doing the above DISM attempts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as it is a production server and one of the software items on it has a deadline coming soon for this to be installed.

What I tried is shown above